# Perl script to dynamically monitor web pages

Tags: perl, transactions, monitoring, nagios

I'm tweaking a perl script that I use to monitor sites (response times etc.) and I'm running into issues using Nagios::WebTransact.

I want to be able to post to a page on one of my sites, get a response, and use the values in that response to post to the next page. It doesn't look like Nagios::WebTransact supports this. I read it has "limited ability to respond to dynamic web pages".

Is there an alternative I can use or possibly a feature of WebTransact that I am unaware of?

Comment: What do you mean by 'dynamic web page'?  Can you clarify this, I may have a script you could use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution ended up being to parse the response text, which you can get using check() on the transaction. Not the solution I was hoping for but it was still workable.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Nagios::WebTransact, but would suggest looking into [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/~petdance/WWW-Mechanize-1.62/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm)

Comment: If "dynamic web pages" means JavaScript, that doesn't appear to offer a solution.

Comment: ... in which case `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox` or `WWW:Selenium` might be a better option